# Why is JavaScript Array Loop printing extra line?

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, console

The following is supposed to print the 4 names like so:

```
alice

bob

michelle

timmy
```

Code:

```
function Person (name, age) {
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
}

family = new Array();
family[0] = new Person ("alice", 40);
family[1] = new Person ("bob", 42);
family[2] = new Person ("michelle", 8);
family[3] = new Person ("timmy", 6);


for (var i = 0; i< family.length; i++) {
    console.log(family[i].name);
}
```

It does this but it also prints a 5th line:

```
alice

bob

michelle

timmy

alicebobmichelletimmy
```

What is the reason for this?

Comment: works fine here: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ehSLk/)

Comment: `console` varies across environments - what browser are you using?

Comment: Tested on Chrome, it doesn't print that last line. See http://jsfiddle.net/8yAp4/.

Comment: Tested pasting into Firebug console and works fine there as well. There is nothing wrong with the code above.

Comment: Well, in both Chrome and node you do get one extra line, printing `undefined`. This is the return value of `console.log`. But not seeing the array members printed out like that.

Comment: I'm learning javascript on codecademy.com - it shows up on the console there

Comment: @nrabinowitz is this just due to the codecademy environment then?

Comment: @JosephByrne - very likely, not familiar with the environment so I can't say for sure.

Comment: put var family=[]; instead of family = new Array();

Comment: and put `family.push(new Person ("alice", 40))` without index of element in array.